# Is regularization (Ridge/Lasso) implemented in statsmodels' GLM model?

Tags: regression, linear-regression, statsmodels, lasso-regression

I have the following model:

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import glm

modelSpecification = glm(
                      formula="wage ~ workhours + gender",
                      data=train,
                      family=sm.families.Gaussian()
)

fittedModel = modelSpecification.fit()
```

However, I am curious if I can use the regularized fit method in combination with GLM. I have only seen it being applied to OLS regression. Similarly, I could only find the documentation for the OLS model (https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit_regularized.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit_regularized).

So I am asking if I can do:

```
fittedModel = modelSpecification.fit_regularized(...)
fittedModel.summary()
```

Currently I get `NotImplementedError` when I try to do this, but I think the `.summary()` part is not implemented and Lasso is (but I am not sure).

Comment: `fit_regularized` works and implements elastic net https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.fit_regularized.htm . However, there are no standard errors for it (unless refit=True)

Answer (score 0):

See: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit_regularized.html

There is a L1_wt term that penalizes the Lasso fit.  If 0, the fit is a ridge fit, if 1 it is a lasso fit.